# while grep multiple files, how do I stop after first match?

Tags: grep

I have a list of patterns in a text file, for which I use bzgrep to match on multiple files:

```
for pattern in $(cat ~/patterns.txt); do echo $pattern; bzgrep -i $pattern *.bz2; done
```

How do I make bzgrep (grep) stop after the first match of the current pattern (I need it stop completely, not stop on the current file being grep'ed) and go on to the next pattern.  I have read about "-m 1" parameter, but I think it only stops on the current file.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Pipe the output of the grep to `head -n 1`; that will pull (& pass on) the first line and ignore the rest (i.e. kill the source pipe).

Answer (score 5):

```sh
for pattern in $(< ~/patterns.txt); do
  echo "$pattern"
  for i in *.bz2; do
    bzgrep -i "$pattern" "$i" && break
  done
done
```

You may wish to add a -H to grep to display filename:line rather than just line.

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to use the `-q` (`--quiet` aka `--silent`) switch.  Then check to see if the command completed successfully or not.  This outputs nothing and stops searching immediately upon finding a match, and just returns success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
for i in  ~/bin/*; do grep -m 1 lua $i /dev/null && break; done
```

The same works with `bzgrep`; after the first successful match you exit the loop.

Including `/dev/null` gets you the filename in case you have some sort of dinosaur grep that doesn't recognize the `-H` option.

Comment: Using `grep -m 1` seems like the best answer, surprised it had no previous votes

Answer (score 0):

If you use ack, at http://betterthangrep.com/, you can use the -1 flag for exactly this reason.